# Saving data from multiple textfields to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

i'm looking for a way to save data to User Defaults based on a condition, and also a better way to do the actual saving because I feel like the way i'm doing it uses too much code. My code is supposed to save the data from the textfields if all but one are filled in. Currently, the data saves correctly when I open and close the app when the if statement isn't present, but with the if statement it does not save at all. Here is my code, feel free to change it around. Any help is appreciated!

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        if (billingTextView.text != "" && FirstName.text != "" && LastName.text != "" && Email.text != "" && PhoneNumber.text != "" &&  Address.text != "" && City.text != "" && PostalCode.text != "" && Country.text != "" && State.text != "" ){
            billingTextView.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "profileName")
            FirstName.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName")
            LastName.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastName")
            Email.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email")
            PhoneNumber.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "phoneNumber")
            Address.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "address")
            Address2.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "address2")
            City.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "city") ?? ""
            PostalCode.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "postalCode")
            Country.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "country")
            State.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "state")

        }
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        if (billingTextView.text != "" && FirstName.text != "" && LastName.text != "" && Email.text != "" && PhoneNumber.text != "" &&  Address.text != "" && City.text != "" && PostalCode.text != "" && Country.text != "" && State.text != "" ){


            billingTextView.text = defaults.string(forKey: "profileName")
            FirstName.text = defaults.string(forKey: "firstName")
            LastName.text = defaults.string(forKey: "lastName")
            Email.text = defaults.string(forKey: "email")
            PhoneNumber.text = defaults.string(forKey: "phoneNumber")
            Address.text = defaults.string(forKey: "address")
            Address2.text = defaults.string(forKey: "address2")
            City.text = defaults.string(forKey: "city")
            PostalCode.text = defaults.string(forKey: "postalCode")
            Country.text = defaults.string(forKey: "country")
            State.text = defaults.string(forKey: "state")



        }
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if (billingTextView.text != "" && FirstName.text != "" && LastName.text != "" && Email.text != "" && PhoneNumber.text != "" &&  Address.text != "" && City.text != "" && PostalCode.text != "" && Country.text != "" && State.text != "" ){


            defaults.set(billingTextView.text ?? "", forKey: "profileName")
            defaults.set(FirstName.text ?? "", forKey: "firstName")
            defaults.set(LastName.text ?? "", forKey: "lastName")
            defaults.set(Email.text ?? "", forKey: "email")
            defaults.set(PhoneNumber.text ?? "", forKey: "phoneNumber")
            defaults.set(Address.text ?? "", forKey: "address")
            defaults.set(Address2.text ?? "", forKey: "address2")
            defaults.set(City.text ?? "", forKey: "city")
            defaults.set(PostalCode.text ?? "", forKey: "postalCode")
            defaults.set(Country.text ?? "", forKey: "country")
            defaults.set(State.text ?? "", forKey: "state")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "profileName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "firstName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "lastName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "phoneNumber")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "address")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "address2")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "city")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "postalCode")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "country")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "state")

        billingTextView.text = ""
        FirstName.text = ""
        LastName.text = ""
        Email.text = ""
        PhoneNumber.text = ""
        Address.text = ""
        Address2.text = ""
        City.text = ""
        PostalCode.text = ""
        Country.text = ""
        State.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func proceedToPaymentSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (billingTextView.text != "" && FirstName.text != "" && LastName.text != "" && Email.text != "" && PhoneNumber.text != "" &&  Address.text != "" && City.text != "" && PostalCode.text != "" && Country.text != "" && State.text != "" ){


            UserDefaults.standard.set(billingTextView.text!, forKey: "profileName")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(FirstName.text!, forKey: "firstName")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(LastName.text!, forKey: "lastName")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Email.text!, forKey: "email")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(PhoneNumber.text!, forKey: "phoneNumber")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Address.text!, forKey: "address")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Address2.text!, forKey: "address2")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(City.text!, forKey: "city")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(PostalCode.text!, forKey: "postalCode")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Country.text!, forKey: "country")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(State.text!, forKey: "state")

            print("Data Saved!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: A better way is to put all user data into a struct and read and write the struct as `Data` with Codable. If you declare all struct members as non-optional and assign empty strings as default values you get rid of all the ugly *empty* checks. By the way is it intended to **read** the values in `viewDidDisappear`?

Comment: ahh i assume that would be with ?? "" and yeah, its supposed to read the data so it appears  inside the texfield when you restart it.